# Attempt failing on codewars challenge (Scramblies)

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to solve the CodeWars kata [Scramblies](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c04b4cc56a697bb0000048/javascript):

> Complete the function `scramble(str1, str2)` that returns `true` if a portion of `str1` characters can be rearranged to match `str2`, otherwise returns `false`.
>
> #### Notes:
>
> - Only lower case letters will be used (a-z). No punctuation or digits will be included.
> - Performance needs to be considered.
>
> #### Examples
>
> ```
> scramble('rkqodlw', 'world') ==> True
> scramble('cedewaraaossoqqyt', 'codewars') ==> True
> scramble('katas', 'steak') ==> False
> ```

My code doesn't pass all the tests in this kata. Apparently it fails when `str2` repeats a letter that is not in `str1`.

For example, this is one of the errors:

> Incorrect answer for inputs:
>
> ```
> s1='scriptjavx'
> s2='javascript'
> ```
>
> : expected `true` to equal `false`

Here's my solution

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  let sameChar = ""
  for (char of str2) {
    if (str1.includes(char)) {
      sameChar += char
    }
  }
  if (str2 == sameChar) 
    return true
  else
    return false;
}
```

Can you tell me how I could fix it?

Comment: You should include the link and copy and paste the task here so we can know what your functions should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `str1.includes(char)` still allows the found character to be found again at the same spot. For example, if `str2` is "aa" and `str1` is "a" you can see how that goes wrong. That single "a" in `str1` should only serve once for a match, not twice.

A solution is to maintain a count per character:

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  if (str2.length > str1.length) return false;
  const counts = {};
  for (let c of str1) {
    counts[c] = (counts[c] || 0) + 1
  }
  for (let c of str2) {
    if (!counts[c]) return false;
    counts[c]--;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made great logic but you need to test it both ways, you only tested on `str2`, I added your same test on `str1`

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  let sameChar1 = ""
  let sameChar2 = ""
  for (char of str1) {
    if (str2.includes(char)) {
      sameChar1 += char
    }
  }
  for (char of str2) {
    if (str1.includes(char)) {
      sameChar2 += char
    }
  }
  if (str1 == sameChar1 && str2 == sameChar2) 
    return true
  else
    return false;
}
console.log(scramble('scriptjavx', 'javascript'))
```